# Running MS Teams in a dockerized envrironment with MS Edge

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-teams, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to run Microsoft Teams inside a docker container that is running ubuntu 22.04. I've installed MS Edge and webdriver. I'm using selenium with python to automate this. When I try to go to this url (using the selenium script) `https://teams.microsoft.com/` , I see a sign-in page. After signing in, the script never moves forward to the Teams page. Instead it keeps on loading this page `https://teams.live.com/_` . I tried the same with Chrome browser in a docker environment and I was getting similar behaviour.

These are the edge options for the selenium script:

```
        edge_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        edge_options.use_chromium = True
        edge_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        edge_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        edge_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        edge_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        edge_options.add_argument("--window-size=1280x720")
        edge_options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
        edge_options.add_argument("--v=1")
        edge_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        edge_options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        edge_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
        edge_options.add_argument("--disable-features=msEdgeSync")
        edge_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        edge_options.add_argument("-disable-default-apps")

        chrome_prefs = {
            "profile.default_content_settings": {"cookies": 1},
            "profile.block_third_party_cookies": False,
            # ... other preferences
        }

        edge_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)
        edge_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
```

and this is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Avoid warnings by switching to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install dependencies required for Edge
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    software-properties-common \
    xvfb \
    unzip

# Add Microsoft Edge repository
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | apt-key add - \
    && add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable main"

# Add your downloaded .deb file to the container
COPY microsoft-edge-stable_119.0.2151.97-1_amd64.deb /tmp/

# Install Microsoft Edge
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/microsoft-edge-stable_119.0.2151.97-1_amd64.deb || \
    apt-get install -f -y && \
    rm -f /tmp/microsoft-edge-stable_119.0.2151.97-1_amd64.deb

# Check if the Microsoft Edge binary exists and output the version.
RUN which microsoft-edge-stable
RUN microsoft-edge-stable --version || true

RUN EDGE_DRIVER_VERSION="119.0.2151.97" && \
    echo "Edge Driver Version: ${EDGE_DRIVER_VERSION}" && \
    wget -q https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/${EDGE_DRIVER_VERSION}/edgedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip edgedriver_linux64.zip && \
    mv msedgedriver /usr/local/bin/ && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/msedgedriver && \
    rm edgedriver_linux64.zip

# Set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99


# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Install sudo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo

UN groupadd -r chrome && \
    useradd -r -m -g chrome -G audio,video,sudo chrome && \
    mkdir -p /home/chrome/user_data && \
    mkdir -p /home/chrome/reports && \
    chown -R chrome:chrome /home/chrome && \
    chmod -R 777 /home/chrome/user_data

# Give chrome user passwordless sudo privileges
RUN echo 'chrome ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/chrome && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/chrome 

RUN mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/

# Create the JSON file with the policy
RUN echo '{ \
    "ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox": true, \
    "URLAllowlist": [ "https://*", "ms-teams:*", "teams.live.com*" ] \
    }' > /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json

# Adjust permissions on the file and directory
RUN chmod -R 775 /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed

# Switch to chrome user
USER chrome
WORKDIR /home/chrome

COPY . .

# Copy the Python script
COPY --chown=chrome:chrome . /home/chrome


# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000


RUN chmod +x /home/chrome/start.sh

# Start with the shell script
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/chrome/start.sh"]
```